# Convert scala array to Map of item counts

Tags: arrays, scala

I'm looking for a neat way of converting a scala array to a map containing the frequency of the items occurring in the array.

For eg. :

Given an array like:

```
val arr = Array("one", "one", "two", "three", "one", "three")
```

I want a map:

```
Map("one" -> 3, "two" -> 1, "three" -> 2)
```

I can do this by writing a function such as

```
import scala.collection.mutable

def counter[T](arr: Array[T]) = {
  val temp = mutable.Map[T, Int]()
  for (i <- arr) {
    if (temp.contains(i)) temp(i) += 1
    else temp(i) = 1
  }
  temp
}

counter(arr)
```

I'd like to know if this can be done more efficiently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use `groupBy(identity)` and `mapValues(_.length)`:

```
scala> val arr = Array("one", "one", "two", "three", "one", "three")
arr: Array[String] = Array(one, one, two, three, one, three)

scala> arr.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(one -> 3, three -> 2, two -> 1)
```

**Update:** This isn't more efficient than your code (and I think it's not possible to beat), but it is definitely more readable. The [`groupBy` method](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L325) aggregates all the identical (because we used `identity`) values to one `Array`, that has some overhead compared to just incrementing count.

**Update 2:** As noted in the comment, the output is **not serializable** because the `mapValues` just wraps the map and evaluates the function on each `get`. You can *materialize* the map by `map(identity)` on the wrapped map:

```
arr.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length).map(identity)
```

but it's not very nice code.

Comment: Thanks! +1 for being more readable. This way throws a ``java.io.NotSerializableException`` error while doing the same thing in Spark though. Hence accepting the alternate answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
arr.groupBy(identity).map{case (x,y) => x -> y.size}
```